# Fonts shrink after upgrade to Meteor 0.8.0

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just updated an app from 6.6 to Meteor version 0.8.0 and all of my fonts have shrunken to something ridiculously small, and I'm not overriding the default meteor-bootstrap-3 css at all.

What is causing this?  The upgrade of jquery?

Comment: Click on a piece of text in your browser and choose "Inspect element" or similar. You should see the stack of CSS rules applied to the element and where they come from. This should allow you trace the problem. Also, double check that you didn't scale your browser – CMD+0 or CTRL+0 to reset scaling. Sorry that I point the latter out, but that's exactly how I fixed this problem once :-)

Comment: I don't mind the scale comment, however I'm currently using the scaling just to read the text ;)

Comment: I suspect that the package maintainer for meteor-bootstrap-3 has made changes, but I know quite a few packages have changed with the upgrade to meteor, and I don't think the bootstrap-3 package changed between meteor versions